# how to add price discount percentage by a category in zen cart?

Tags: zen-cart

I know that there is an option for the special price for a specific product But I want to set the discount price percentage for a category so that discount price will be applied automatically for each product in that specific category.

Is there any option in zen cart or any module for this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in Zen Cart using "Salemaker".  See admin->catalog->SaleMaker.